# Differences in numeric representation between read.csv and data.table::fread

Tags: r, data.table

I noticed some strange behaviour reading csvs into R using `data.table::fread()` (version 1.14.2) and `read.csv()`, where certain numeric values are not identical across the two read methods. A minimal example (using the value I first noticed the behaviour with) is:

```
fname <- tempfile()
df <- data.frame(x = -0.175247)
write.csv(df, fname, row.names = FALSE)
f1 <- read.csv(fname)
f2 <- data.table::fread(fname, data.table=FALSE)
f1 - f2
```

For me, this returns:

```
> f1 - f2
              x
1 -2.775558e-17
```

In trying to figure out why this particular number seems to result in floating point issues, I then did a search to see which numbers would return this non-equivalence, writing:

```
x <- (1:200000)/1000000
df <- data.frame(x = x)

fname <- tempfile()
write.csv(df, fname)
f1 <- read.csv(fname)
f2 <- data.table::fread(fname, data.table=FALSE)

# huh, this doesn't match to anything
which(df[,1] == 0.175247)

# okay, so the numeric differences exist in the vector, not just from the read
# stage
identical(x[175247], 0.175247)
x[175247] - 0.175247
```

Unexpectedly, doing this I found that this issue of non-equivalence doesn't necessarily arise in the csv reading stage, but is also present in R itself. Moreover, the gaps between the numbers that present this issue have a strange regularity, with many of the gaps between offending numbers being exactly divisible by 562. I can't figure out why these numbers have an issue, and not others, or why they would occur in these intervals..

```
> num_diffs <- which((f1[,2] - f2[,2]) != 0)
> diff(num_diffs)
 [1]   562   562   562  7672  1124 13377  1124  1124 11129  1124  1124  1967  2248  7757  1124  2248  2248  2248 11129  2248  2248  8881  2248  2248  2248  6633  4496
[28]  3934  4385   111  2137  8881   111  4496 11018   111  4496 11018   111  4496  6522  4496   111  4496
```

To get to the point, I have three questions:

1. What is it about these numbers that creates these differences in how they are stored in R? I assume it's something to do with floating point representation..
2. Why do `data.table:::fread` and `read.csv` specifically have different representations of the numbers?
3. Is there a way to force either `fread` or `read.csv` to have the same behaviour as the other for the purposes of comparison (I'm comparing large, somewhat complicated objects that contain these data.framed within them, and it would be convenient if they behaved in the same way so I can just check that the objects are the same with `identical()`)?

Comment: FWIW, `readr::read_csv()` matches `data.table::fread`; `scan(fname, skip = 1) ` matches `read.csv()`. `print(x, digits = 22)` is another good way to examine these results.

Comment: `all.equal()` is is a utility to compare R objects testing ‘near equality’. `all.equal(f1, f2)` returns `TRUE` with a default tolerance of `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` which is 1.490116e-08 on my machine.

Comment: If it might help, I think that this problem was solved (at least for some cases) in the current dev version of `data.table` (1.14.3).  see [HERE](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html#cb17).

Comment: nice! @B.ChristianKamgang, can you please post that as answer??

Comment: Thanks for that @B.ChristianKamgang, very useful. Updating to the dev version (1.14.3), the inconsistency found in the first code block is no longer present. However, rerunning the third code block (starting ```x <- (1:200000)/1000000```) still identifies 34 inconsistencies, compared to the 44 previously. Given that this appears to be related to a known issue, I will now also submit it as an issue on github